# margin set to first line of textView

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to set start margin only for the first line of TextView (Not first line of each paragraph)? I have used the following code:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("this is a test"+"\n"+"this is a test");
s.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(30, 0), 0, s.length(), 0);
textView .setText(s);
```

Here start margin is getting set for all lines of the Paragraph.. I don't want that. I want start margin to be applied for first line only.. Pls help..

Comment: I think,you have to use white space only..

Comment: then you can take two separate textviews: 1 for 1st paragraph and other for remaining ones. just set span for 1st textview and let other be as they are. i think,you don't have any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been suggested here, I also think the best solution is to simply add a few spaces at the beginning. If you only need the margin space at the very first line of the `TextView`, I don't see any reason why you'd need to do something really advanced.

If you need to change or use the text in the TextView at a later point, you can just use the `substring()` method to get only a part of the string, i.e. `s.substring(2, s.length());`

It's not a perfect solution, but I think it'll do.

Comment: The trouble is diff characters need diff length of UI to show, (ex: 'm' needs more length than 'i'), and a space length is not equal with all characters length.

Answer (score 6):

You actually already answered your own question.
All you need to do is to set span lenght to `1` instead of `s.length()`.

```
if (s.length() > 0) {
    s.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(30, 0), 0, 1, 0);
}
```

That way margin will only be applied to the first paragraph.