# How can I add margin or padding between 2 lines in spannable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, spannablestring

I am using a spannable to create a string in 2 lines where each line has different font.
It works fine except one thing.
How can I add some margin between the first string with the second string?

So I do:

```
String a = "First line";  
String b = "Second line";  
SpannableString spannableName = new SpannableString(a + "\n" + b);  
spannableName.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(activity, R.style.my_style),0,a.length(), 0);
```

and my_style

```
<style name="my_style">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/size</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mycolor</item>
    </style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to have some padding/margin between `a` and `b`.
The paddings/margins in my style are big because I wasn't sure if they are applied or not (test numbers)

Comment: check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7693253/1283715)

Comment: Have you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198155/adding-a-padding-margin-to-a-spannable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has to be a property of the UI control you are using.

I assume you are setting the text into a `TextView`. You can use `textView.setLineSpacing(addvalue, multiplyValue)`. This will add `addValue` units to the spacing and multiply it `multiplyValue` times.

Similarly, if you want it set through style you can add these values to your style:

```
<item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">SoemDPValue</item>
<item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">someNumber</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it with [RelativeSizeSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html):

```
String a = "First line";
String b = "Second line";
SpannableString spannableName = new SpannableString(a + "\n" + b);
spannableName.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(activity, R.style.my_style),0,a.length(), 0);
spannableName.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), a.length(), a.length() + 1, 0);
```

RelativeSizeSpan will make the "\n" character 1.5 bigger than the "a" and "b" string.