# How to add margin between lines in a SpannableString?

Tags: android, kotlin

line one and line two are different `TextViews` separated with a 8dp margin vertically

line three and four is one `TextView` that uses a `SpannableString`.
Is there a way i can add the same spacing(8dp) with a Span?

I tried using a `LineHeightSpan`, the result is the image below.

```
append("line three")
appendLine()
appendLine()
setSpan(
    LineHeightSpan.Standard((8 * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()),
    0,
    length,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
append("line four")
```

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078831/how-can-i-add-margin-or-padding-between-2-lines-in-spannable) could help

Answer (score 0):

Please code below code.

```
append("line three")
append("\n")
append("\n")
setSpan(
    LineHeightSpan.Standard((8 * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()),
    0,
    length,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)
append("line four")
```

Comment: doesn't work, it add more margin but the result isn't the same